# How sum values of a table with decimals

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-table

I have a project in HTML and JS whit a table and input

```
<input type="text" id="suma">


<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>N</td>
<td>NOMBRE</td>
<td>MONTO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Alba</td>
<td>1.200,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Andrea</td>
<td>1.200,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>Jose</td>
<td>1.200,00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
function total(){
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    let total = 0
    for(let i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
        total+=Number(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText)
    }
    const totalInput = document.getElementById('suma')
    totalInput.value=Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(total)

}
```

The script can calculate the total of the MONTO field in the input, but the result is NaN because the values have decimals and thousand separator. The question is, How i can make for the script sum includes decimals and thousands separator? that is to say, with this format: 1.200,00

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just forgot to handle punctuation and number mask. Basically remove all "." and replace the "," for a single "." representing the float part.

```js
function removeNumberMask(value) {
  return value.replaceAll('.', '').replace(',', '.')
}

function total() {
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    const rawNumber = removeNumberMask(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerText)
    total += Number(rawNumber)
  }
  const totalInput = document.getElementById('suma')
  totalInput.value = Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(total)
}

total();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="suma">


<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>NOMBRE</td>
      <td>MONTO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Alba</td>
      <td>1.200,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Andrea</td>
      <td>1.200,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Jose</td>
      <td>1.200,00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an European country to format this way : `1.200,00` (like Germany)

also `Intl.NumberFormat` accept
`minimumFractionDigits` has option
(or `maximumFractionDigits` )

```js
const
  inSuma     =  document.getElementById('suma')
, cssSelect  = '#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(3)'
, Total      = document.querySelector('#myTable tfoot tr td:nth-of-type(2)')
, optionIntl = { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }
, getNum  = val => Number(val.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.'))
  ;
total()
  ;
function total()
  {
  let sum = [...document.querySelectorAll(cssSelect)]
          .reduce( (s,cell) => s + getNum(cell.textContent), 0)
          ;
  Total.textContent = inSuma.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE',optionIntl).format(sum);
  }
```

```css
#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(3) { color: blue; }

#myTable tfoot tr td:nth-of-type(2) { color: red; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="suma">

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>N</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>MONTO</td></tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td> Alba   </td><td>1.200,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td> Andrea </td><td>1.200,00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td> Jose   </td><td>1.200,00</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Total:</td><td> xxx </td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to try it .... but already I tried your code, work perfectly in the format wanted, Thank you very much.
I include a input for filter the table, but this code dont sum the visible rows only,  the result continue being the Total of the table, How i can adjust it

Comment: @LuisJose the correct html5 table respect usage is using  [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) and [`<tfoot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot) for your Total , you should use them !

Comment: There is return, whit the total of the table perfectly, but when i filter the table, te result in the input whit ID "suma" continue to be the total of the table. For example, I write "Alba" in a other inpunt as criteria to filter the table and te result is 3.600,00 and not 1.200,00, that to say,  the sum must to be the result of the visibles rows only. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @LuisJose Stop that! You can't change the terms of your question as your imagination evolves, Stackoverflow is not an "on demand code service" and I don't take my patience as an opening to exploit myself.